# Jquery - Expanding an item's parent container when child link receives focus

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-animate

I have a container element which can be expanded upon being clicked.
This container contains some child  tags.
When these child tags are reached whilst tabbing through the elements on the page I would like the container to expand to show them.

To do this I have written the following function...

```
$("#inlineSummaryWrapper a").focus(function(){
  $("#inlineSummaryWrapper").animate({"height":"100px"})
  });
```

However this doesn't work!

If a better coder than myself could help, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT to add example markup:

```
<div id="inlineSummary" class="displayToggle">
  <h2>Summary</h2>
  <div id="inlineSummaryWrapper">
   <dl>
    <dt>Product:</dt>
    <dd class="define"> <span class="NA"><a href="product.aspx" tabindex="92">Required</a></span> </dd>
   </dl>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you have more than 1 `#inlineSummaryWrapper`? This could be a problem as JQuery will only find the first instance when searching on ID values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
<style type="text/css">
#inlineSummaryWrapper {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>

<div id="inlineSummary" class="displayToggle">
    <h2>Summary</h2>
        <div id="inlineSummaryWrapper">
        <dl>
            <dt>Product:</dt>
            <dd class="define"> <span class="NA"><a href="#" tabindex="92">Required</a></span> </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#inlineSummaryWrapper a").focus(function(){
     $(this).closest("#inlineSummaryWrapper").animate({"height":"100px"});
    return false;
});
</script>
```

If your javascript is above the divs, wrap it inside a:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//javascript here
});
```

So that it fires off once the DOM has finished loading.

http://jsfiddle.net/YgjzD/6/

Comment: `$(this)` is not necessary since you are using the parent ID

Comment: I've added the mark-up to the opening post. The fiddle seems to work so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in-situ.

Comment: This is due to your link going to another page. Below the first line in the focus function, add `return false;`

Comment: If you don't want the link to go anywhere.. change the href to `#` or `javascript:;`

Comment: @KyleR This was certainly something that hadn't occurred to me. I've just tried it but the container div stubbornly refuses to co-operate :)

Comment: The fiddle is working how you want it to right? Can you copy your document ready function too.

Comment: @KyleR Apologies I didn't look at your fiddle. I cut and pasted this into my Jquery file removing everything else and it would appear that it was clashing with something else as it works as expected on its own. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm still confused as to why the focus is on a link, I would of imagined it to work on input focus: http://jsfiddle.net/YgjzD/9/ - but thats just a guess. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("#inlineSummaryWrapper a").focus(function(){
    $(this).closest("#inlineSummaryWrapper").animate({"height":"100px"})
});
```

$(this) is the `a` and .closest() looks for the closest parent that matches the selector.

Comment: If it is to use an ID selector, you can avoid using closest() and select directly the element by id, which will be much faster.

Comment: @DidierGhys That's assuming that they correctly only use the ID once on the page.  There's nothing to stop them using it as many times as they like.

Comment: or you can use - $(this).parent().animate({"height":"100px"});

Comment: @shershen That's assuming that `#inlineSummaryWrapper` _is_ the parent.  There's no way of knowing that from the code above.  If it's known 100% that it will be the parent then obviously using .parent() would be the fastest and best method.

Comment: @Archer oh, sily me, i read only JS code and didn't pay attention to example markup ((

Comment: @shershen I don't think the markup was there when you commented ;)